# Java Lambda to map a List<Object[]> to a (x[0] -> increment from starting value) map

Tags: java

I have a `List<Object[]> events` where `[0]` in each row is an ID that I need. Also I have an `int startSeq` which is a certain starting number.

I need to obtain a `Map<Integer,Integer>` where **Event ID -> startSeq + i** where i is an increment by 1 from `startSeq`.

Example:

```
int startSeq = 6;
List<Object[]> events = dao.getEvents();
// ((Object[])events.get(0))[0] = 200676, ((Object[])events.get(1))[0] = 204561, ...
200676 -> 6
204561 -> 7
205156 -> 8
```

Problem: If I go with an `IntStream` option as the basis for my stream, I don't have a way to track the index of the List (key) in `toMap`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = IntStream.range(startSeq, startSeq +events.size())
                                    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                      x -> /* Can't track List, no relation to IntStream*/
                                                      Function.identity()))
```

If I go with the List Stream option as the basis, I can't track the sequential increment in the value of `toMap`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = events.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                      x -> (Integer)x[0], 
                                                      y -> /* How to relate i increment from startSeq? */)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the range of (startSeq, startSeq + events.size()) and substract startSeq from each index to map to list elements:

```
int startSeq = 6;
List<Object[]> events = List.of(new Object[]{200676,"foo"}, new Object[]{204561,"bar"}, new Object[]{205156,"baz"});

Map<Integer,Integer> map =
    IntStream.range(startSeq, startSeq + events.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry((Integer)(events.get(i-startSeq)[0]), i))
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(map);
```

If you need keep insertion order:

```
....
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,(x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to do the following:

```
final int startSeq = 6;
final List<Object[]> events = List.of(new Object[] {1}, new Object[] {2}, new Object[] {3});
Map<Integer,Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, events.size())
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> (Integer)events.get(i)[0], i -> startSeq + i));
```

Please note, this may work only if `startSeq` and `events` can be made `final` or `member` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AtomicInteger`:

```java
AtomicInteger startSeq = new AtomicInteger(6);
Map<Integer, Integer> map = events
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        x -> (Integer)x[0], 
        x -> startSeq.getAndIncrement()
    ));
```

or `int[]`

```java
int[] startSeq = {6};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = events
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        x -> (Integer)x[0], 
        x -> startSeq[0]++
    ));
```

Comment: Could I do it without an `int[]` array, just as `startSeq++`?

Comment: Do not use stateful operations in streams.

Comment: @gene.b, no, as explained earlier `startSeq` must be effectively final

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.  You may need to slightly alter how I dereferenced the event object you mentioned.

- stream the indices for the array size
- map the value and index to an array
- then collect the values from the array and place in the map.

```
int startSeq = 6;
Map<Integer, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, events.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new int[] { (int)events.get(i)[0], i + startSeq })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0],
                arr -> arr[1]));
```